# Populating dropdownlist in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with a dropdownlist. It's always empty,even though when debugging there is 4 different entries in the list that's set in asp-items as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwreR.jpg

What am I doing wrong?

ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectRole { get; set; }

public string RoleId { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
 model.SelectRole = _roleManager.Roles?.Select(s => new SelectListItem
 {
     Value = s.Id,
     Text = s.Name
 });
```

View:

```
<select asp-for="RoleId" asp-items="@Model.SelectRole" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Problem is that you are using self closing `select` tag as follows:

```
<select asp-for="RoleId" asp-items="@Model.SelectRole" class="form-control" />
```

**It would not generate the select list properly.**

You can tune your code as follows:

**In the ViewModel:**

```
public SelectList RoleSelectList { get; set; }

public string RoleId { get; set; }
```

**In the controller method:**

```
var roleList = _roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new {r.Id, r.Name}).ToList();
model.RoleSelectList = new SelectList(roleList, "Id","Name");
```

**In the View:**

```
<select asp-for="RoleId" asp-items="Model.RoleSelectList" class="form-control">
   <option value="">Select Role</option>
</select>
```

Now everything should work fine.